# Can't remove space on top of nav_host_fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview

I just implemented a bottom navigation (AS's default - File -> New -> Activity -> Bottom Navigation Activity) Everything is fine except for a space on the top of the `nav_host_fragment`.

[image: wrong space]

Since it was generated in a ConstraintLayout, I tried to clean the constraints and set the top constraint with `parent`, setting `margin` to '0dp' and set `height` to `match_constraint`.

I unsuccessfully deleted the constraints and tried over and over again.

I used `Clean Project`.

I changed to RelativeLayout and set arguments like this:

```
 <fragment
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_above="@+id/nav_view"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />
```

But the space between `nav_host_fragment` and the top is still there.

Here's the lyout file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

    <fragment
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_above="@+id/nav_view"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: That looks like the `android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"` on the `<RelativeLayout>`.

Comment: What _Theme_ are you using? Maybe one that is reserving space for the "ActionBar" ?

Comment: @MikeM. That's exactly what was causing the space. I can't believe I didn't noticed that! Thank you!

Comment: You may post this comment as an answer, so I can mark as the right one for this question.

Comment: No problem. I'm good. :-) Nothing major. Just a slight oversight. Please feel free to post an answer yourself, or to just delete this question, if you'd rather. Thank you, though. I appreciate the offer. Cheers!

Answer (score 70, accepted):

**Remove** this line from your ***Relative Layout***.

```
android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
```

Comment: In 2021 the default "Bottom Navigation Activity" in Android Studio still adds a paddingTop to the BottomNavigationView's parent layout for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

Answer from @Mike

> That looks like the android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize" on the

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

    <fragment
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_above="@+id/nav_view"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

in my layout i have also space bottom of navigation host fragment i count track out.

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    
        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbarMain"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:contentInsetStart="@dimen/_minus10sdp">
    
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
    
                <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtTitleMain"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingStart="0dp"
                    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/_15sdp"
                    android:text="@string/app_name"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_14ssp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
    
            </LinearLayout>
    
    
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar>
    
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_below="@id/toolbarMain"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />
    
    
        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />
    
    </RelativeLayout>
```